# how can I enable all the actuators into Spring-MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I tried in the .properties file to put these 2 lines of code:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.refresh.enabled=true
```

But doesn't work. My web application is on Spring-MVC.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({
        EndpointAutoConfiguration.class , PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration.class , HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class ActuatorConfig {

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public EndpointHandlerMapping endpointHandlerMapping(Collection<? extends MvcEndpoint> endpoints) {
        return new EndpointHandlerMapping(endpoints);
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public EndpointMvcAdapter metricsEndPoint(MetricsEndpoint delegate) {
        return new EndpointMvcAdapter(delegate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is not working?  Is it that you can not access the endpoints while it is running?

Comment: Can you check if there are message like `Exposing XX endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuactor'`in console output or log files after AP startup?

Comment: @fedup it works just for localhost:myIP/metrics and I want to configure enable all the actuators(info, health, beans...) in .properties file without a create @Bean/method in my class(ActuatorConfig).

Comment: You shouldn't need the class you have.  Instead, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably just accessing the endpoint with the wrong path.  /actuator/ is the default path.  You can change this something else via the yaml (properties) configuration.  See management.endpoints.web.base-path.

This is how it works for me.  Include the actuator dependency in the pom.xml.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Include this in your application.yml (or properties file with the "." notation.)

```
    management:
      endpoints:
        web:
          exposure:
            include: "*"
```

Then access the metrics endpoints with

```
    http://yourdomain:yourport/actuator/metrics
```

Also read this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators) for more details.

Comment: my application is springMVC, not spring Boot, because for spring-MVC not work with these settings, also in url path, I don't need of /actuator/. It works just with http://yourdomain:yourport/metrics.